# Apply recode pattern to many columns

Tags: python, pandas, replace, recode

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

```
Name, Year, V1, V2, V5, V10, V12...
```

This Table contains about 40 Vx Variables. The values of these variables can be 1-5. I want to recode them so

```
1-3 = 0 and
4-5 = 1
```

I know how to replace data for one column like this

```
Table['V1_F'] = Table['V1'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x <4 else 1)
```

But I do not know how to apply this on multiple columns efficiently or is there now way around writing this replace code for each column?
Best would be something like 'Do it for all columns except `Name` and `Year`.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all columns names to variable and compare for boolean mask, then convert `True/False` to `1/0` by casting to integers:

```
cols = Table.columns.difference(['Name','Year'])
Table[cols] = (Table[cols] >= 4).astype(int)
```

Or by [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
Table[cols] = np.where(Table[cols] < 4, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions presented below

- [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) if more sophisticated function required
- your logic is binary, binary truth matrix and change back to integer representation

```
df = pd.DataFrame({**{"Name":np.random.choice(["this","that","other"],15),"Year":np.random.choice(range(1990,2021),15)},
             **{f"V{i}":np.random.randint(1,5,15) for i in range(10)}})

df2 = df.copy()
# solution 1
df.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if c.startswith("V")]] = df.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if c.startswith("V")]].applymap(lambda v: 0 if v<=3 else 1)
# solution 2
df2.loc[:,[c for c in df2.columns if c.startswith("V")]] = (df2.loc[:,[c for c in df2.columns if c.startswith("V")]]<=3).astype(int)
```

| Name | Year | V0 | V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 | V5 | V6 | V7 | V8 | V9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| this | 1998 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| that | 2010 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| this | 2004 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| this | 1992 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| this | 1990 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| this | 2020 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| this | 2016 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| other | 1997 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| that | 2000 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| that | 2020 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| that | 1991 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| other | 2015 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| this | 2020 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| other | 2005 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| other | 2008 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |